# Can an insecure docker registry be given a CA signed certificate so that clients automatically trust it?

Tags: ssl, docker, ssl-certificate, docker-registry, certificate-authority

Currently, I have set up a registry in the following manner:

```
docker run -d \
  -p 10.0.1.4:443:5000 \
  --name registry \
  -v `pwd`/certs/:/certs \
  -v `pwd`/registry:/var/lib/registry \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/certificate.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/private.key \
  registry:latest
```

Using *Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72*

I have obtained my certificate.crt, private.key, and ca_bundle.crt from Let's Encrypt.  And I have been able to establish https connections when using these certs on a nginx server, without having to explicitly trust the certificates on the client machine/browser.

***Is it possible to setup a user experience with a docker registry similar to that of a CA certified website being accessed via https, where the browser/machine trusts the root CA and those along the chain, including my certificates?***

Note:

I can of course specify the certificate in the clients docker files as described in this tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#use-self-signed-certificates . However, this is not an adequate solution for my needs.

Output of `curl -v https://docks.behar.cloud/v2/`:

```
*   Trying 10.0.1.4...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to docks.behar.cloud (10.0.1.4) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: docks.behar.cloud
* Server certificate: Let's Encrypt Authority X3
* Server certificate: DST Root CA X3
> GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: docks.behar.cloud
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 2
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Sun, 10 Sep 2017 23:05:01 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host docks.behar.cloud left intact
```

> **Short answer: Yes.**
>   My issue was caused by my os not having a build in trust of the root certificates from which my SSL certificate was signed by.  This is likely due to the age of my os.  See the answer from Matt for more information.

Comment: So you mean you want to autotrust a a self-signed CA https registry on the system?

Comment: No, sorry I'll try to make my post more clear.  Since the certificate authority, which provided/signed my certificate, is generally trusted by browsers, I was hoping to understand why docker does not simply trust them as well.

Comment: What does `curl -v https://registryname/v2` give for your registry? Please add the output to your question

Comment: Updated with output of curl -v

Comment: Can you append `/` at the end of the url and update the output

Comment: Done, looks the same except for the 301 is now a 200

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154099/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-benjamin-behar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker will normally use the the OS provided CA bundle, so certificates signed by trusted roots should work without extra config.

Let's Encrypt certificates are [cross signed](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) by an [IdentTrust root certificate](https://www.identrust.com/certificates/trustid/root-download-x3.html) (DST Root CA X3) so most CA bundles should already trust their certificates. The [Lets Encrypt root cert](https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem.txt) (ISRG Root X1) is also distributed but will not be as widespread due to it being more recent.

Docker 1.13+ will use the host systems CA bundle to verify certificates. [Prior to 1.13 this may not happen if you have installed a custom root cert](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/#understanding-the-configuration). So if you use `curl` without any TLS warning then `docker` commands should also work the same.

Comment: So you are implying that, if I was able to `curl -v https://docks.behar.cloud` then that would suggest that a command such as `docker push docks.behar.cloud/my-ubuntu` would succeed?  

However, In my current situation it isn't: `Get https://docks.behar.cloud/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`, so maybe something else is wrong?

Comment: Add "insecure-registry": "docks.behar.cloud" to your Docker `daemon.json` file.  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/ and https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/ for more info.

Comment: @BenjaminBehar Yes, that's what I think should happen, I just found some version info that could impact that behaviour though, are you on a version prior to 1.13?

Comment: @GHETTO.CHiLD `insecure-registry` kind of defeats the purpose of the certs.

Comment: @Matt i agree. i've updated my answer accordingly.  i belive this question is more of a configuration question.  using certs with DTR does require some additional setup and override of the default configuration.yaml.  DTR supports LetsEncrypt natively so there should be no issues.

Answer (score 1):

To have DTR recognize the [certificates](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#tls) you need to edit the [configuration file](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#overriding-the-entire-configuration-file) so that you specify your certs correctly.  DTR accepts and has special parameters for `LetsEncrypt Certs`.  They also have [specific requirements](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#letsencrypt) for them.  You will need to [make a configuration file](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/cmd/registry/config-example.yml) and mount the appropriate directories and then there should be no further issues with `insecure-registry` errors and unrecognized certs.

```
...
http:
  addr: localhost:5000
  prefix: /my/nested/registry/
  host: https://myregistryaddress.org:5000
  secret: asecretforlocaldevelopment
  relativeurls: false
  tls:
    certificate: /path/to/x509/public
    key: /path/to/x509/private
    clientcas:
      - /path/to/ca.pem
      - /path/to/another/ca.pem
    letsencrypt:
      cachefile: /path/to/cache-file
      email: emailused@letsencrypt.com
    ...
```

Comment: The certificates are installed on the registry

Comment: agreed, ive updated my answer to better reflect the question which is how to i setup a DTR with certificates, which requires some changes to the configuration.yaml.